# android clear in costom arrayadapter java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, android, arrays, adapter

i want to use clear() in my `CostomArrayAdapter`, but i get always this error:

```
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:638)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.remove(AbstractList.java:75)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at java.util.AbstractList.removeRange(AbstractList.java:658)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at java.util.AbstractList.clear(AbstractList.java:466)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.clear(ArrayAdapter.java:258)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at de.fterhorst.pictoriusvertretungsplan.SimpleArrayadapterDay.dayempty(SimpleArrayadapterDay.java:235)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at de.fterhorst.pictoriusvertretungsplan.SimpleArrayadapterDay.getView(SimpleArrayadapterDay.java:177)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1655)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-08 18:15:01.960: E/AndroidRuntime(27192):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

when i make it so:

this.clear();
this.notifyDataSetChanged();

on my `ArrayAdapter`:

```
public class CostomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
```

can i use clear() on a arrayadapter,
i hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 15):

The error you are getting isn't from calling `clear()` on the `ArrayAdapter`. You are using a `List` implementation (possibly the default) which doesn't implement a `clear()` method and therefore the parent class', ie. `AbstractList` implementation is used, which throws `UnsupportedOperationException`.

If you pass an array to the constructor

```
public ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects) {
    init(context, resource, 0, Arrays.asList(objects));
}
```

it calls `Arrays.asList()` which returns a `List` which you cannot `add()` to, `remove()` from or `clear()`.

Use this constructor

```
public ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects) {
    init(context, resource, 0, objects);
}
```

by passing a `LinkedList` or `ArrayList` containing your objects.

Comment: i want to remove a item from my list is this possible with arraylist?

Comment: @johan Instead of using the constructor that takes an array, use the one that takes a `List` and pass an `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` or whichever other modifiable list flavor you want.

Answer (score 3):

If an array is used to initialize and ArrayAdaptor, the array is converted into an AbstractList. AbstractList does not support `remove()` or `clear()`.

You can use a `List` which exposes a clear.remove, like an `ArrayList`, instead of an array to initialize.

Edit: To make it clear as suggested, it is not really converted to an `AbstractList`. Its converted to a **special** `ArrayList` which extends `AbstractList` and has no clear/remove methods.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the ArrayList returned by Arrays.asList() has an _is a_ relationship with AbstractList. Also, because its a different implementation of AbstractList than the regular ArrayList, I chose to exclude it.

Comment: I don't know why you deleted your answer. I just don't like your wording of _converted into an AbstractList_. It's not converted into an `AbstractList` since that class is abstract. It is converted into a `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` which extends `AbstractList`.

Answer (score 1):

in Kotlin, the result of
`toList()`, also does NOT respond to `clear()` function.

You should use `toMutableList()` when setting your `ArrayAdaptor` out of another collection or a literal.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what `Sotirios Delimanolis` and `rocketboy` said, I guess you should fire clear operation on reference of your custom adatper, say for example,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) Listview.getAdapter();

if(adapter!= null)
{
    adapter.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I believe that is what OP is doing, but the underlying `List` object doesn't implement a `clear()` method and defaults to `AbstractList`'s implementation.